# Error adding packages in Julia 1.3.1 after installation

Tags: julia

I am new to Julia. I have installed the latest Julia 1.3.1 version successfully in my Mac. Post installation, I am trying to add a couple of packages namely StatsBase.jl and DataFrames.jl. It's throwing me the following error. I have tried cleaning up .julia folder and reinstalling. Nothing helped.

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> Pkg.add("StatsBase.jl")
   Cloning default registries into `~/.julia`
   Cloning registry from "https://github.com/JuliaRegistries/General.git"
     Added registry `General` to `~/.julia/registries/General`
ERROR: The following package names could not be resolved:
 * StatsBase.jl (not found in project, manifest or registry)
Please specify by known `name=uuid`.
Stacktrace:
 [1] pkgerror(::String) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/Types.jl:113
 [2] #ensure_resolved#101(::Bool, ::typeof(Pkg.Types.ensure_resolved), ::Pkg.Types.EnvCache, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/Types.jl:936
 [3] #ensure_resolved at ./none:0 [inlined]
 [4] #add#25(::Bool, ::Pkg.BinaryPlatforms.MacOS, ::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.add), ::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/API.jl:97
 [5] add(::Pkg.Types.Context, ::Array{Pkg.Types.PackageSpec,1}) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/API.jl:72
 [6] #add#24 at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/API.jl:69 [inlined]
 [7] add at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/API.jl:69 [inlined]
 [8] #add#21 at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [9] add at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/API.jl:67 [inlined]
 [10] #add#20(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(Pkg.API.add), ::String) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/API.jl:66
 [11] add(::String) at /Users/julia/buildbot/worker/package_macos64/build/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.3/Pkg/src/API.jl:66
 [12] top-level scope at REPL[4]:1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not include the `.jl` extension when referring to the package. The proper command is `Pkg.add("StatsBase")`.

Comment: or shorter form `pkg"add StatsBase"`

Comment: Thanks! The answer worked. The shorter form by @PrzemyslawSzufel also works!